# Thymeleaf error : An error happened during template parsing

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I don't know what is wrong with my view but it is impossible for it to work, the view always gives an error even if idStudent is set correctly.I don't know if there is also another way to do it, but thymeleaf always fail

here is the error - > `Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "student.id == {idStudent}" (template: "/content/course/list-course-student" - line 55, col 24)`

here is my controller

```
@GetMapping("/list-courses-student")
public String listCoursesByUser(@RequestParam(required = false) int page,Model model) {
    
    User currentUser = userService.findByName(this.currentUser.getUsername());  
            
    int numberPages = coursesService.getNumberPages();
    List<Course> courses = coursesService.findAllCourses(page,true);
    
    model.addAttribute("coursesDisponibles",courses);
    model.addAttribute("numberPages",numberPages);
    model.addAttribute("currentPage",page);
    model.addAttribute("idStudent",currentUser.getStudent().getId());

    return "/content/course/list-course-student";
}
```

My view

```
<div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
                    <table class="table table-hover text-nowrap">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Profesor</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Code</th>
                                <th>Inicio</th>
                                <th>Final</th>
                                <th>Acciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <th:block th:each="course : ${coursesDisponibles}">

                                <tr>
                                    <td
                                        th:text="${course.teacher == null} ? 'No Asignado' : ${course.teacher.nombre}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${course.nombre}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${course.descripcion}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${course.code}"></td>
                                    <td
                                        th:text="${#temporals.format(course.inicioDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy')}"></td>
                                    <td
                                        th:text="${#temporals.format(course.finalDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy')}"></td>


                                    <td>
                                        <th:block th:each="student : course.Estudiantes">
                                        
                                            <th:block th:if="${student != null}">
                                                <th:block th:if="${student.id == {idStudent}}">
                                                <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="">Añadido</a>
                                                <a class="fas fa-inbox ml-3"
                                                    th:href="${'/tareas/list-tareas-student?page=1&course=' + {course.id}}"></a>
                                                </th:block>
                                            </th:block>
                                            
                                            <th:block th:unless="${student == null}">
                                                <a
                                                    th:classappend="${course.teacher  == null} ? 'btn btn-primary btn-sm disabled':'btn btn-primary btn-sm' "
                                                    th:href="${'/courses/add?idCourse=' + {course.id} + '&idStudent=' + {idStudent}}">Añadir</a>
                                            </th:block>
                                        </th:block>
                                    </td>
                            </th:block>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please, try `${student.id == idStudent}`. Note how you are using braces again inside your expression.

Comment: it's still failing  `Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "student.id == idStudent" (template: "/content/course/list-course-student"`

Comment: The whole stack track will have more details.  Not enough information here...

Answer (score 0):

The exception you're most likely experience is `NullPointerException`, because I think you have a wrong `th:each` declaration:

```
<th:block th:each="student : course.Estudiantes">
```

instead of

```
<th:block th:each="student : ${course.Estudiantes}">
```

Thus, expression `th:if=${student.id == idStudent}` throws `NullPointerException` as it tries to access the `id` property on a null `student` object.

Also note that in order to preventer other `NPE`'s you can use a `?` operator in your expressions, like this: `${student?.id}`.